# dpdk vmxnet3 clear stats missing (?) implementation

Tags: dpdk

`dpdk` PMDs implement `stats_reset` of `rte_ethdev.h`:`struct eth_dev_ops` in order to reset port statistics.
PMD `vmxnet3` doesn't register it under

```
static const struct eth_dev_ops vmxnet3_eth_dev_ops = {
    ...
    .stats_get            = vmxnet3_dev_stats_get,
    .xstats_get_names     = vmxnet3_dev_xstats_get_names,
    .xstats_get           = vmxnet3_dev_xstats_get,
    ...
```

There are only `get` functions, but no `reset`.

- Does it mean `vmxnet3` cannot clear port statistics?
- Is there a way to implement it?

The strange thing is that no one complains it over the internet. Looks like I'm the only one that needs it.

- dpdk versions 17.11.1, dpdk-stable-18.02.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean vmxnet3 cannot clear port statistics?

Yes, the PMD does not implement the functionality.

> Is there a way to implement it?

We can workaround it in the code or implement the same workaround in the PMD and send a patch to dev@dpdk.org as described here: https://www.dpdk.org/contribute/

The idea behind the workaround is that we can store base stats:

```
stats_reset() {
    base_stats = eth_stats_get()
}

stats_get() {
    return etc_stats_get() - base_stats
}
```

Feel free to ask if it is not clear.

Comment: Do you know why they chose not to implement it? Is there any limitation?

Comment: I am not sure, but looks like those stats are shared between the cores, so it might be not that trivial to implement the reset... The PMD guide says "PMD provides the basic functionality of packet reception and transmission". Source:  http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/vmxnet3.html

Comment: Now it's implemented :)
https://mails.dpdk.org/archives/dev/2018-September/112389.html

Comment: Did you submit the patch?

Comment: Yes. And now I also know what it wasn't implemented, as the maintainer said: "... the reason of this not supported is because the device backend doesn’t support it"

Comment: @hudac congrats on becoming a DPDK contributor! ;)